# How do I share a class between Blazor wasm and .Net 5?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly, .net-standard-2.1, .net-5

I have a Blazor wasm app (.net standard 2.1), and i want to share a .Net 5 class library. I thought that when .Net 5 came out that there would be harmony among the .net core and .net standard universes, but i'm not seeing it in the latest versions of my .Net 5 SDKs, runtimes, and VS 2019.

I get a project ref error in my Blazor app when i reference the .net 5 libs, but all is fine if i reference a .net standard 2.1 lib.

Do i have to downgrade my shared libs to .net standard 2.1?

I'm running:
.Net SDK:

```
3.1.400-preview-015203
5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6
```

.Net runtimes:

```
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2   
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0-preview.7.20364.11
```

VS 2019 Preview:

```
Version 16.7.0 Preview 6.0
```

Comment: Which lib?  It should just work, in general.

Comment: My own class libraries to share across projects (a "common" project, for instance containing consts, enums, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Blazor wasm app (.net standard 2.1)

You should upgrade that to .net 5 (preview) too of course.

In the standard Hosted Webassembly template the shared class library is a net5.0 project.

See the [upgrade instructions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-7/).

Comment: I do have .net 5 preview installed, and yes, if i click the [x] hosted option on project creation i do get the .net 5 target, but my blazor app isn't a hosted app.

Comment: But what platform _is_ your Blazor app then?  You say "(.net standard 2.1)" which is the version _before_ net5. Open the csproj file.

Comment: In the blazor wasm csproj file:<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>. Even if i create a new blazor wasm project, the most-recent framework i can choose in vs is .net std 2.1 - unless i check the hosted option as we discussed.

Comment: That's a misconfiguration then. I can (VS  Version 16.7.0 Preview 6.0) select net5 regardless of the Hosted checkbox. Trry updating or reppairing.

Comment: Weird. I added the .net 5 tag manually, and it compiled. Then i created a new blazor wasm project from scratch (after having done it 5 other times), and it now has .net 5 as the default. So it's a problem with VS2019 Preview 7. Thanks for the help!